# Where can i see emails of visitors logged in with FB Login button on my website?

Tags: facebook, facebook-login

i want to retrieve my visitors emails when they login on my website via FB Login Button. This is the code i have:

```html
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_PT/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=xxxxxxxxx";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
function login() {
    FB.login(function(response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
            // connected
        test();
        } else {
            // cancelled
        }
    }, { scope: 'email' });
    }

function test() {

    console.log('Welcome! Gathering information... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {

        console.log('Welcome, ' + response.name + '.' + ' Email: ' + response.email + ' Facebook ID: ' + response.id);
    });
}
</script>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-max-rows="1" data-size="xlarge" data-show-faces="false" data-auto-logout-link="false" scope="email">Login with Facebook</div>
```

I´m no coder, i gathered the above code searching on the internet, dunno if it is correct.

FB Login Button is present, and permissions popup appears and also i see no errors. But where can i see the emails of the visitors who logged in?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You see it where you store it. If you do console.log it will be seen in the webbrowser console

Comment: WizKid, can you tell me how to store it in a file, for instance?

Comment: Then you will have to send the value to the server and have the server write the value to a file

Comment: WizKid can you post a working example please?

Comment: No. If you want someone to code for you then go and hire someone

Comment: I don´t understand why you bothered answering in the first place. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
FB.api('/me', {fields: 'email'}, function(response) {...
```

It´s called "Declarative Fields", see changelog for v2.4 of the Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4

This may be useful for you too, just in case you need more information: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

Comment: I think he has bigger problems :)

Comment: luschn, i spent all afternoon trying to figure this out...as i said i´m no coder, and facebook doesn´t provide working examples for "humans", i´m stuck here :(

Can you post a working example please?

Comment: that´s not how it works on stackoverflow, i´m sorry. this is a platform for programmers only. if you want your work done, you need to go to one of the countless freelancer platforms and hire a developer. we are happy to help when you got stuck, but this is no place to get work done for free ;)

Comment: This is probably 2 lines of code, if you call that work that´s fine, i wouldn´t mind providing to someone else if i knew. One thing you can´t say is that telling other people to read entire encyclopedias is helping though...
Thank you both for your time.

Comment: it´s only 1 line of code, and that line is in my answer...either way, i have included a link to a tutorial, that one is definitely working.